# How to add custom class to body element for some routes - nexjts

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to add my custom class to some pages. for example

all pages must be this class `fixed-header` exception this routes:

```
/cart/step-1 

/login
```

this class add or remove to body element.

```
<body className="bg-gray fixed-header"
```

but I don't know how I can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom `_document.js` and `_app.js` in your pages directory.

A small util to check if class exists on body *(to avoid duplicate class, thanks to suggestion by @juliomalves)*:

```js
// ./utils/hasClasses
const hasClasses = () =>
  document.body.classList.contains("bg-gray") &&
  document.body.classList.contains("fixed-header");
export default hasClasses;
```

#### Server Side rendering

In `_document.js`, use the `__NEXT_DATA__` prop to get access to the current page,
check if the page is in your allowed routes, and add the classes to body.

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {

  // Add more routes here if you want to use the same classes  
  allowedRoutes = ["/login", "/cart/step-1"];

  getColor() {
    const { page } = this.props?.__NEXT_DATA__;
    if (this.allowedRoutes.includes(page))
      return "bg-gray fixed-header";
    return "";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body className={this.getColor()}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

The above code always runs on the server. Classes doesn't get appended to the body on client-side navigation.

#### Client side rendering

To fix the above issue, use the same logic in `_app.js` in a `useEffect`, so that it adds the correct class when rendering on the client.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import "../styles.css";
import hasClasses from "./utils/hasClasses";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const { pathname: page } = useRouter();
  const allowedRoutes = ["/login", "/cart/step-1"];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasClasses() && allowedRoutes.includes(page))
      document.body.className += "bg-gray fixed-header";
    else if (hasClasses()) {
      // Don't want the styles in other pages, remove if exists.
      // Up to your implementation on how you want to handle this.
      document.body.classList.remove("bg-gray");
      document.body.classList.remove("fixed-header");
    }
  });
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

This solves the issue where client side navigation correctly applies the class on the allowed route. The code in `_document.js` makes sure that when a page is server rendered, it is sent downstream with the correct class applied so that it doesn't cause a flash of incorrect styles on the client.

Comment: Nice SSR solution using `__NEXT_DATA__`. Just a small nitpick on the CSR code, you may want to check if `bg-gray fixed-header` classes exist before appending them to the `body` when the page is in the allowed routes. This prevents adding duplicate classes, for example when navigating from `/login` to `/cart/step-1`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and quickest solution. Add this code into each component where you want different classes on the `<body>`.

```
useEffect( () => { document.querySelector("body").classList.add("bg-gray fixed-header") } );
```